# How to handle large files while reading it with python xlrd in GAE without giving DeadlineExceededError

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, xlrd

I want to read a file having size 4 MB using python xlrd in GAE.

i am getting the file from Blobstore. Code used is given below.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=temp_file)
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for col_no in range(sh.ncols):
```

its gives me DeadlineExceededError.

```
 book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=file_data)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appid/app-version.369475363369053908/xlrd/__init__.py", line 416, in open_workbook
  ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appid/app-version.369475363369053908/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 756, in open_workbook_2007_xml
x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~appid/app-version.369475363369053908/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 520, in own_process_stream
 for event, elem in ET.iterparse(stream):
 DeadlineExceededError
```

But i am able to read files with smaller size.

*Actually i need to get only first few rows(30 to 50) of the file. Is there any other method, other than adding it as a task and getting the details using channel API to get the details with out causing deadline error ?*

**What i can do to handle this....?**

Comment: Run the actual processing in a deferred task.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I need only first few rows of the file. Is that posible to get first 30 to 50 rows using xlrd with out this Deadline error. i need the data for displaying so if i use task then i have to use channel API for getting details. Is there any other method for this...?

Answer (score 0):

I read a file about 1000 rows excel and it works okay the library.
I leave a link that might be useful https://github.com/cjhendrix/HXLator-SpaceAppsVersion/blob/master/gae/main.py

the code I see that this crossing of columns and rows must be at lists for each row

example:

```
 wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=inputfile.read())
 sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
 for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
   val_row = sh.row_values(rownum)
   #here print element of list
   self.response.write(val_row[1]) #depending for number for columns
```

regards!!!